# Open file, delete zeros, sort it - NASM

Tags: sorting, assembly, nasm, glibc

I am currently working on some problems and this is the one I am having trouble with. To make it all clear, I am a beginner, so any help is more than welcome.

Problem:

> Sort the content of a binary file in descending order. The name of the file is passed as a command line argument. File content is interpreted as four-byte positive integers, where value 0, when found, is not written into the file. The result must be written in the same file that has been read.

The way I understand is that I have to have a binary file. Open it. Get its content. Find all characters while keeping in mind those are positive, four-byte integers, find zeros, get rid of zeros, sort the rest of the numbers.

We are allowed to use glibc, so this was my attempt:

```
section .data
    warning db 'File does not exist!', 10, 0
    argument db 'Enter your argument.', 10, 0

    mode dd 'r+'
    opened db 'File is open. Time to read.', 10, 0


section .bss
    content resd 10
    counter resb 1

section .text

    extern printf, fopen, fgets, fputc

global main
main:
    push rbp
    mov rbp, rsp
    push rsi
    push rdi
    push rbx

    ;location of argument's address
    push rsi 

    cmp rdi, 2
    je .openfile
    mov rdi, argument
    mov rax, 0
    call printf
    jmp .end

.openfile:
    pop rbx
    ;First real argument of command line
    mov rdi, [rbx + 8]
    mov rsi, mode
    mov rax, 0
    call fopen
    cmp al, 0
    je .end

    push rax

    mov rdi, opened
    mov rax, 0
    call printf

.readfromfile:
    mov rdi, content
    mov rsi, 12 ;I wrote 10 numbers in my file
    pop rdx
    mov rax, 0
    call fgets
    cmp al, 0
    je .end

    push rax


    mov rsi, tekst
    pop rdi
.loop:
    lodsd
    inc byte[counter]
    cmp eax, '0'
    jne .loop

    ;this is the part where I am not sure what to do. 
    ;I am trying to delete the zero with backspace, then use space and 
    ;backspace again - I saw it here somewhere as a solution
    mov esi, 0x08
    call fputc  
    mov esi, 0x20
    call fputc
    mov esi, 0x08
    call fputc
    cmp eax, 0
    je .end
    jmp .loop

.end:
    pop rdi
    pop rsi
    pop rbx
    mov rsp, rbp
    pop rbp
    ret
```

So, my idea was to open the file, find zero, delete it by using backspace and space, then backspace again; Continue until I get to the end of the file, then sort it. As it can be seen I did not attempt to sort the content because I cannot get program to do the first part for me. I have been trying this for couple of days now and everything is getting foggy.

If someone can help me out, I would be very grateful. If there is something similar to this problem, feel free to link it to me. Anything that could help, I am ready to read and learn.

I am also unsure about how much information do I have to give. If something is unclear, please point it out to me.

Thank you

Comment: You can't delete using backspace from a file. In any case, just read everything into memory, sort them, truncate the file and write the whole thing without the zeroes (which will be at the end so you can just use a smaller length). You might want to write it in C first.

Comment: To open binary file you should use "r+b" mode for `fopen`. Also "four byte positive integers" in binary file means simple `dword`, i.e. values from 0 to 2^32-1. There's little sense to use `fgets` on binary file, and there's little sense to compare with ASCII `'0'` character as the content is already binary, not ASCII encoded... either that, or your interpretation is correct and the one who wrote the task is mixing up different terms randomly. Depending on the amount of zeroes in the file it may be faster to "read, sort, write-up-till-first-zero", or "read, collapse-zeroes, sort, write"

Comment: You might as well `mmap` the file, sort in descending order, and then truncate it to remove the zeros at the end.  You don't want to read it one character at a time with `fputc`, you're dealing with dword elements.

Comment: `fputc` clobbers RDI, so your repeated calls need to set RDI before every `call`.  This is another reason why `fputc` sucks for this.

Answer (score 2):

For my own selfish fun, an example of memory area being "collapsed" when dword zero value is detected:

to build in linux with NASM for target ELF64 executable:

```
nasm -f elf64 so_64b_collapseZeroDword.asm -l so_64b_collapseZeroDword.lst -w+all
ld -b elf64-x86-64 -o so_64b_collapseZeroDword so_64b_collapseZeroDword.o
```

And for debugger I'm using `edb` (built from sources) (the executable doesn't do anything observable by user, when it works correctly, it's supposed to be run in debugger single-stepping over instructions and having memory view over the `.data` segment to see how the values are moved around in memory).

---

source file `so_64b_collapseZeroDword.asm`

```
    segment .text

collapseZeroDwords:
; input (custom calling convention, suitable only for calls from assembly):
;   rsi - address of first element
;   rdx - address beyond last element ("vector::end()" pointer)
; return: rdi - new "beyond last element" address
; modifies: rax, rsi, rdi
; the memory after new end() is not cleared (the zeroes are just thrown away)!

; search for first zero (up till that point the memory content will remain same)
    cmp     rsi, rdx
    jae     .noZeroFound    ; if the (rsi >= end()), no zero was in the memory
    lodsd                   ; eax = [rsi], rsi += 4
    test    eax, eax        ; check for zero
    jne     collapseZeroDwords
; first zero found, from here on, the non-zero values will be copied to earlier area
    lea     rdi, [rsi-4]    ; address where the non-zero values should be written
.moveNonZeroValues:
    cmp     rsi, rdx
    jae     .wholeArrayCollapsed    ; if (rsi >= end()), whole array is collapsed
    lodsd                   ; eax = [rsi], rsi += 4
    test    eax, eax        ; check for zero
    jz      .moveNonZeroValues      ; zero detected, skip the "store" value part
    stosd                   ; [rdi] = eax, rdi += 4 (pointing beyond last element)
    jmp     .moveNonZeroValues

.noZeroFound:
    mov     rdi, rdx        ; just return the original "end()" pointer
.wholeArrayCollapsed:       ; or just return when rdi is already set as new end()
    ret

global _start
_start:     ; run some hardcoded simple tests, verify in debugger
    lea     rsi, [test1]
    lea     rdx, [test1+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test1+4*4      ; no zero collapsed

    lea     rsi, [test2]
    lea     rdx, [test2+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test2+3*4      ; one zero

    lea     rsi, [test3]
    lea     rdx, [test3+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test3+3*4      ; one zero

    lea     rsi, [test4]
    lea     rdx, [test4+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test4+2*4      ; two zeros

    lea     rsi, [test5]
    lea     rdx, [test5+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test5+2*4      ; two zeros

    lea     rsi, [test6]
    lea     rdx, [test6+4*4]
    call    collapseZeroDwords
    cmp     rdi, test6+0*4      ; four zeros

    ; exit back to linux
    mov     eax, 60
    xor     edi, edi
    syscall

    segment .data
    ; all test arrays are 4 elements long for simplicity
        dd 0xCCCCCCCC       ; debug canary value to detect any over-read or over-write
test1   dd 71, 72, 73, 74, 0xCCCCCCCC
test2   dd 71, 72, 73,  0, 0xCCCCCCCC
test3   dd  0, 71, 72, 73, 0xCCCCCCCC
test4   dd  0, 71,  0, 72, 0xCCCCCCCC
test5   dd 71,  0, 72,  0, 0xCCCCCCCC
test6   dd  0,  0,  0,  0, 0xCCCCCCCC
```

I tried to comment it extensively to show what/why/how it is doing, but feel free to ask about any particular part. The code was written with simplicity on mind, so it doesn't use any aggressive performance optimizations (like vectorized search for first zero value, etc).

Comment: An interesting implementation of an _in-place_ solution.